# Can't connect to an open Excel app

Tags: c#, excel, windows, process

I'm successfully connecting to opened Excel file on my computer (64 bit Windows 8.1 and Excel 2007 32bit) via the

```
Excel.Application xlApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

But on another computer (64 bit Windows 7 SP1 and Excel 2007 32bit) I can't do it this way.
The only that I noticed, on my computer process named just "EXCEL.EXE", but on another, it named "EXCEL.EXE *32".

Can it be the reason, and how I can solve it?

**Update**

The problem appears when I launch my exe-file as administrator. I receive standard for GetActiveObject exception -- "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException". On my computer, everything works fine. The user on another computer included in the administrators' group, so I don't know what the difference.

Comment: Probably though it really depends on how it was registered via COM. Have you checked the registry HK_Classes to see what name it was registered under?

Comment: `I can't do it this way.` What happens when you try?

Comment: @mjwills I have finally found a reason, but the problem remained. It appears when I launch my exe-file as administrator. I receive standard for GetActiveObject exception -- "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException". On my computer everything works fine. The user on another computer included in the administrators' group, so I don't know what the difference.